# Nagios retry interval when they have OK or UP state

Tags: centos, nagios, nrpe, nagiosxi

I configure one Linux Host to Nagios Monitoring Server Using NRPE Plugin.
For this I follow the below URL

http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-add-linux-host-to-nagios-monitoring-server/

I have to check some services of Linux Host.
For monitoring linux host and services of that host, I am using nagios log(`/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log`)

First time all good in my nagios log that showing me as below status

```
SERVICE ALERT: test.testing.local;Service Tomcat;OK;SOFT;6;TOMCAT OK
```

When my Service status is change to non-OK state than it showing me on log

```
SERVICE ALERT: test.testing.local;Service Tomcat;CRITICAL;SOFT;4;TOMCAT CRITICAL
```

But I want that if my Service status is not change to non-OK state than again after 1 minute it show me on log

```
SERVICE ALERT: test.testing.local;Service Tomcat;OK;SOFT;6;TOMCAT OK
```

and currently that is not happening.

My services.cfg file content is given below

```
define service {
    host_name                       test.testing.local
    service_description             Service Tomcat
    check_command                   check_nrpe!check_service_tomcat
    max_check_attempts              10
    check_interval                  1
    retry_interval                  1
    active_checks_enabled           1
    check_period                    24x7
    register                        1
}
```

I am using Nagios 4.2.2 and CentOS 7.

Comment: Did the answer help get it working?  Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are after is from the Nagios 4 Core docs [here](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#service)

> check_interval:   This directive is used to define the number of "time units" between regularly scheduled checks of the host. Unless you've changed the interval_length directive from the default value of 60, this number will mean minutes. More information on this value can be found in the check scheduling documentation.
>
> retry_interval:   This directive is used to define the number of "time
> units" to wait before scheduling a re-check of the hosts. Hosts are
> rescheduled at the retry interval when they have changed to a non-UP
> state. Once the host has been retried max_check_attempts times without
> a change in its status, it will revert to being scheduled at its
> "normal" rate as defined by the check_interval value. Unless you've
> changed the interval_length directive from the default value of 60,
> this number will mean minutes. More information on this value can be
> found in the check scheduling documentation.

If you were to set your check_interval to 1 minute (which is pretty frequent, the default as you can see is 60) you will **retry** every 1 minute 10 times (max_check_attempts in your config) without a change in status then it will give you an OK/UP state.